# How do I find in GitHub the pull-request that resulted in the elimination of the non-terminal `pseudo-destructor-name` from the C++ grammar?

Tags: c++, github, language-lawyer

You'll notice that the non-terminal *pseudo-destructor-name* was present in the grammar as late as in N4713. But I can't find the pull-request that resulted in its elimination from the C++ grammar using Blame.

Comment: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/search?q=pseudo-destructor-name&type=Commits, except that there was no PR.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer What am I missing? When I do the search I get [this](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/search?q=pseudo-detructor-name&unscoped_q=pseudo-detructor-name)

Comment: de**s**tructor, not detructor

Comment: @LanguageLawyer That was great. Thanks. Sorry for my distraction.